# Connect to serial, issue a command, read result, capture it and exit

Tags: serial-port, serial-console

I have some device, connected to serial port. Actually, it is `Arduino` based temperature sensor.

I wish to write a script, which will connect to serial port, send a command to device, receive it's answer, print it to `stdout` and exit.

What is correct way to do this?

Usually, when accessing local program, it is ok to redirect it's output. For example, this is how I read `CPU` temperature.

```
datetime=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
cputemp=$(sensors atk0110-acpi-0 | sed "s/CPU Temperature:[^0-9]*\([0-9\.]\+\).*/\1/;tx;d;:x")
echo "$datetime\t$cputemp"
```

Unfortunately, `$()` relies on explicit program end, which is not the case with serial communication. Serial server always online and has no explicit "sessions".

Of course, I can check to line feeds. But is this correct action? May be I should write my `Arduino` program so that it send `Ctrl-Z` after each response or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, you cannot read end-of-file from a serial port. (Ctrl-Z is a microsoft thing). So usually, you read until you have the wanted number
of characters, or until you find a delimiter like newline that signals
the end of the data.

For example, I have a usb serial port with output connected back to input, so any writes to the device simply come straight back.  The following script can retrieve what the device sends:

```
#!/bin/bash
tty=/dev/ttyUSB0
exec 4<$tty 5>$tty
stty -F $tty 9600 -echo
echo abcdef >&5
read reply <&4
echo "reply is $reply"
```

The script connects the serial device as file descriptor 4 for input, 5 for
output, sets the speed and stops the echo you get for a tty, then writes
"abcdef" and newline to the device. Each character will be sent back immediately, but the kernel driver will buffer up some input, so I dont need to start
to read from the device before doing the write. The read ends by default when it
sees a newline, and saves it in the variable `reply`, which is then echoed to stdout. You can put this script inside a `v=$()` type usage.

If your serial device data does not end with a newline, you can specify a different delimiter to the bash read with `-d`. Or if the reply is of a constant
length, you can specify a length with `-n`. If you have binary data, you probably should add `raw` to the stty command to stop any special treatment of input.